# How to login into Microsoft account without using MS Authentication App

Tags: authentication

I am one and only admin into my Microsoft tenant. The two factor authentication is enabled. Now I can not use my Microsoft authentication app, the phone is lost. When I try to login into my Microsoft account it is asking to verify though the authentication app but I can not due to lost of phone. How can I login into the account now?